# How to edit PHP.ini file to enable bigger files upload?

Tags: php, file, upload

I want to code a php file uploader, but for bigger files. What do I have to modify?

Comment: [See Related Configuration Notes](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) in of all the odd places _the manual_

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify upload_max_filesize and post_max_size and make sure that post_max_size is larger than  upload_max_filesize. Change the max_execution_time too.